# how can i read the ISO15693 tags UID

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I have tried to use the tag method

```
byte[] tagId = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
```

But the value changes every time when I read the tag.

How can I read the correct ISO15693 tags id?

Answer (score 2):

After you get the byte array you need to convert the hex byte array to a String

try this function:

```
public String getHexString(byte[] b) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=b.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        sb.append(Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This one works but extra "if(i >= 0)" inside the loop is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following

```
Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

byte[] id = tagFromIntent.getId();
```

Get the Tag Identifier (if it has one).
The tag identifier is a low level serial number, used for anti-collision and identification.
Most tags have a stable unique identifier (UID), **but some tags will generate a random ID 
every time they are discovered (RID)**, and there are some tags with no ID at all (the byte array will be zero-sized).

Comment: Some tags return a new random id.. see the explanation above

Comment: The value of tagFromIntent.getId() is a byte array, change the data type to string and will get the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to find the solution for the same issue and luckily did find what I want, which is a solution to this question. The solution is from another similar post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910931/reading-the-tag-uid-of-mifare-classic-card).

```
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    Log.d(TAG, "UID: " + bin2hex(tag.getId()));

    //To display the UID
    static String bin2hex(byte[] data) {
        return String.format("%0" + (data.length * 2) + "X", new BigInteger(1,data));
    }
```