# How get Mifare Ultralight 16 digits UID reading with Nexus 5

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, mifare, serial-number

I'm very new in NFC for Android. I need very much code example or good tutorial for Java for how get Mifare Ultralight 16 digits UID reading with Nexus 5

I only know how to get 7 digits UID for MifareClassic from here
[Reading the tag UID of Mifare classic card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910931/reading-the-tag-uid-of-mifare-classic-card/16903723#16903723), but there is no examples for Mifare Ultralight.

This is another example to get UID for Mifare Classic. What do I need to change to make it read for Mifare Ultralight? And I don't understand what performs in ByteArrayToHexString()

```
byte[] nfcUID = null;
        if (intent != null && (nfcUID = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)) != null) {

            uid = ByteArrayToHexString(nfcUID);

private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] inarray) { // converts byte arrays to string
        int i, j, in;
        String[] hex = {
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
        };
    String out = "";

    for (j = 0; j < inarray.length; ++j) {
        in = inarray[j] & 0xff;
        i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        i = in & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, MIFARE Classic tags usually have a 4 byte UID (also called nUID). Newer MIFARE Classic tags also have 7 byte UIDs. MIFARE Ultralight tags always have a 7 byte UID.

This UID is what you will get from

```
byte[] uid = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
```

Or from

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
byte[] uid = tag.getId();
```

If you convert that UID into hexadecimal digits (as you indicated with the method in your post), you will get:

- an 8 digit number if the UID has 4 bytes, or
- a 14 digit number if the UID has 7 bytes.

So there is no way that you can get a 16 digit hexadecimal number for a MIFARE Ultralight tag.

As MIFARE Ultrlaight UIDs (or actually any 7 byte UIDs from NXP) have the form `0x04xxxxxxxxxxxx`, converting this to a decimal number would give you at maximum a 16 digit number (`0x04FFFFFFFFFFFF` = 1407374883553279). So you might be trying to achieve this. However, converting a 4 byte UID to decimal would still not result in a 7 digit number.

---

### Converting to hexadecimal representation

You could use something like this to convert the UID from byte array to a string of hexadecimal digits:

```
public static String convertByteArrayToHexString (byte[] b) {
    if (b != null) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(2 * b.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
            final String t = Integer.toHexString(b[i]);
            final int l = t.length();
            if (l > 2) {
                s.append(t.substring(l - 2));
            } else {
                if (l == 1) {
                    s.append("0");
                }
                s.append(t);
            }
        }
        return s.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

This method takes each byte of the byte array, converts it to a 2-digit hexadecimal number and concatenates all these 2-digit numbers into a string.

---

### Converting to decimal representation

```
public static String convertByteArrayToDecString (byte[] b) {
    if (b != null) {
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, b);
        return n.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```